# Difference between NSRange and NSMakeRange

Tags: swift, nsrange, swiftlint

Is there any difference between:

```
NSRange(location: 0, length: 5)
```

and:

```
NSMakeRange(0, 5)
```

Because `Swiftlint` throws a warning when I use `NSMakeRange`, but I don't know why.

Thanks for the Help :-)

Comment: Well for one of them, I know immediately what the values 0 and 5 represent without knowing anything about `NSRange`.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The only difference between them is that

```
NSRange(location: 0, length: 5)
```

is an initializer for `NSRange` while

```
NSMakeRange(0, 5)
```

is a function which creates a new `NSRange` instance (by using the same initializer inside most likely) and actually is redundant in `Swift`. `Swift` has simply inherited it from `Objective-C`. I would stick to the former

Answer (score 7):

Main difference is that

```
NSRange(location: 0, length: 24)
```

is auto-generated struct init method in Swift and

```
NSMakeRange(0, 24)
```

is just a predefined macro that setts location and length

```
NS_INLINE NSRange NSMakeRange(NSUInteger loc, NSUInteger len) {
    NSRange r;
    r.location = loc;
    r.length = len;
    return r;
}
```

In general, result is the same, but if you're Swift use first one and if you're writing ObjC code use second ;)