# lint Legacy Constructor Violation: (legacy_constructor) NSMakeRange in Swift?

Tags: swift, swift3, nsrange, swiftlint

What is the Swift constructor for the code below?

```
NSMakeRange(0, textfield.text!.characters.count)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between NSRange and NSMakeRange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44522626/difference-between-nsrange-and-nsmakerange)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The modern Swift constructor for this is `NSRange(location:length:)`.

```
NSRange(location: 0, length: textfield.text!.characters.count)
```